# Interactive website for linux server

Tags: linux

creation of a website through which can access Linux server and where can execute some operations like executing scripts, firing up some commands. need some expert guidance with some concepts.just guide me how can i achieve through, i have goggled a lot unable to get the proper concepts or methods. or is it even possible.

Comment: Why not just SSH into the server? It's 1000x more secure than anything you are going to build and it's uber interactive.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using something along the lines of [VNC](https://www.realvnc.com/) or [SSH](http://www.tecmint.com/install-openssh-server-in-linux/)? As JNevill pointed out, either of these methods would be infinitely more secure. Also, consider using something like cron for scheduled jobs.

However, sometimes a webpage for running a program on a server may be acceptable. e.g. IoT project. To do this, you would setup an API page using a back-end language like PHP (recommended if you're using Linux). In the back-end language you would check your user credentials, and then run the command.

Some guidelines in doing this:

1. Never allow commands to be entered on the webpage, only allow tasks to be completed using controlled inputs like buttons, selectboxes and sliders. i.e. a button to get an Arduino to close your garage door, or a slider to dim/brighten a light bulb, or a button to start a program to index something, etc.
2. None of these "command buttons" should ever do anything harmful. i.e. delete a folder or file.